# How to get mono-apache-server4 on debian

Tags: mono

I installed mod-mono on debian via `apt-get install mono-apache-server2...`

But when i do `apt-get install mono-apache-server4` it gives me:

> E: Unable to locate package mono-apache-server4

Anyone know how I can get mono-apache-server4 on there?

Comment: On debian stable, this is difficult. You would need to upgrade all of mono to testing and there is no going back. At that point, you will likely have a good chunk of your system upgraded to testing along with it. The good news is that wheezy will be released as stable fairly soon. Porting the packages to stable or compiling from source are both options.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot for the info. Place it as an answer and i'll give you credit. I'll try a different distro. Do you know of any debian-based ones that will make it easy for me to install?

Comment: It would be easy to install on Wheezy.

Comment: @JimParis deploying a virtualized wheezy now. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @JimParis You're right... it was easy. Care to create an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package doesn't exist in the current Debian stable (Squeeze), but it's in testing (Wheezy).  You could compile it yourself or try to find a backport, but the easiest might be to just install Wheezy, which is getting close to becoming the new stable anyway.

Comment: [Now](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52340/14560) if I can only get it to run on the website