# apache virtualhost using mono-apache-server2 not mono-apache-server4

Tags: mono

I know I'm running mono-apache-server4 but when I launch the site mono-apache-server2 is responding.

**Why is my site not using 4.0?**

## See htop:

[image]

## This is what I did:

Installed Debian Wheezy along with apache and mod-mono:

```
apt-get install mono-apache-server2 mono-apache-server4 libapache2-mod-mono libmono-i18n2.0-cil
```

Then I edited the default virtual host file: `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.org
  ServerAdmin myname@mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.org/
  ErrorLog /var/www/logs/mydomain.org.error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/logs/mydomain.org.access.log combined

  MonoServerPath example.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"

  MonoDebug mydomain.org true
  MonoSetEnv mydomain.org MONO_IOMAP=all
  MonoApplications mydomain.org "/:/var/www/mydomain.org/"
  <Location "/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias mydomain.org
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  </Location>
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And restarted apache2:

[image]

## Update:

I reinstalled using:

```
apt-get install mono-apache-server4 libapache2-mod-mono libmono-i18n4.0-all
```

But Jim's answer was the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MonoServerPath example.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
```

should probably be

```
MonoServerPath mydomain.org "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
```

Comment: Good EYE! I also reinstalled using `apt-get install mono-apache-server4 libapache2-mod-mono libmono-i18n4.0-all` the way I had it, I only included 2.0 libraries. But ofcourse it still didn't work until I made your modification.

Comment: @Jim Paris, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 alpha instead of debian wheezy. What mono packages  do I need to install to make your fix work when serving ASP.NET content? June 17 2016. Thank you.